# Copy field from one table to another where fields match

Tags: mysql, sql, copy

I have two tables that I need to import data from where both share a column with the same data.  However one table has a value in it that needs to be copied to another.  I need an sql command that works like below:

Update table1 contenttitle with table2 title where table2 id equals table1 contentid

So essentially it is copied the values from table2 title and inputting them in table 1 contenttitle where the values in table2 id and table1 contentid are equal.

Answer (score 2):

```
update table1 
join table2 on table1.contentid = table2.id
set contenttitle = table2.title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update table1
set table1.content1=table2.content2
from table2 join table1 on table2.contentid=table1.contentid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1
set table1.contenttitle = table2.title
FROM table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id= table2.id
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.